# How to add a class to element programmatically in vuejs on focus event on corresponding input element?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm new to VueJS.
I have an `input` element and a `label` as its placeholder like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" v-model="firstName">
<label>First Name</label>
```

When I focus on `input` I want to add `active` class to `label` tag.
Consider there is very inputs like this in my form. Otherwise I could to use a variable in data section to handle this issue.
Also I could to handle this problem by jQuery but I do not want to.
Can you help me to resolve this by VueJS tools like directives?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need javascript for this? If you are just looking to style the label then you can use:

```
input:focus + label {}
```

But this will only work if the label comes after the input in the html.